# How to remove symbol from string Java

Tags: java, string

I have a string `"00000000800540"` . Always identical length of string. But can change the number of zeros to 8. Instead, 8 can also another number. How to get me the number 800540 from the string?

Comment: do you want to strip all left padded `0` ?

Comment: Yes you can. Share what you have tried out

Comment: @Sanjeev Yes exactly!!!!

Comment: Here's a silly way: `Long.valueOf(str).toString()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
   givenNumberAsString.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "")
```

This will work no matter how long your string is.

Answer (score 1):

A non-regex way:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < str.length() && str.charAt(i) == '0') ++i;
String withoutLeadingZeros = str.substring(i);
```

This will trim all zeros, even if the string is all zeros. If you want to preserve the last zero in this case, change the while loop guard to:

```
i + 1 < str.length() && str.charAt(i) == '0'
```

Comment: I would leave the last digit alone.

Comment: @shmosel noted, and added a modification to handle this if required.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the length of the expected number contained in string, you can use `Integer.parseInt(**string**)` or `Long.parseLong(**string**)`.

```
String st = "00000000800540";
System.out.println(Long.parseLong(st));     // 800540
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(st));   // 800540
```